# phablet-dev-bootstrap: error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_external_koush_Superuser error: Exited sync due to fetch errors

Tags: ubuntu-touch, git

I was trying to run `phablet-dev-bootstrap ../phablet` it was throwing loads of 404 errors then eventually threw a fatal error:

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Server does not provide clone.bundle; ignoring.
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_external_koush_Superuser

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
ERROR:phablet-dev-bootstrap:Error while trying to sync repository
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you been able to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I managed to find some archived IRC logs from 2013, but nobody had an answer. If it's from 2013 not many people have tried to fix it! The logs are at [http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2013/02/24/%23ubuntu-touch.txt](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2013/02/24/%23ubuntu-touch.txt). +Spotlight

Comment: I joined #ubuntu-touch on Freenode and asked around. It's not working for people there. We found CyanogenMod/Superuser instead of CyanogenMod/android_external_koush_Superuser worked, however it doesn't have the proper branches. I think their repositories are broken, furthermore than expected

Comment: I found the source code, it's just a simple python script available at: [https://github.com/mikeshi80/phablet-tools/blob/master/phablet-dev-bootstrap](https://github.com/mikeshi80/phablet-tools/blob/master/phablet-dev-bootstrap) and if we find a working, forked repository for `git://phablet.ubuntu.com/CyanogenMod/android.git` with a branch of `phablet-10.1`, it should work! @Spotlight

Comment: In my script (/usr/bin/phablet-dev-bootstrap) I found it's `phablet-4.4.2_r1` at `https://code-review.phablet.ubuntu.com/p/aosp/platform/manifest.git`.

Comment: Oh yeah I have that too... I tested the online script as well but it didn't work. @Spotlight

Comment: I'm trying replacing the branch to: `phablet-4.3.1_r1` I will comment the results when done...  @Spotlight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38915/discussion-between-spotlight-and-im-on-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38915/discussion-between-spotlight-and-im-on-stack-exchange), we figured out that using a different branch stopped the 404s & 503s & the Superuser issues. I also sent a email to a person who will hopefully fix the repo so we don't have to continue using another branch.

**EDIT:** As of April 27th, 2016, this should be fixed on the main branch.